# Python's support for multi-threading

Tags: python-multithreading

I heard that python still has this global interpreter lock issue. As a result, threads execution in python are not actually multi-threaded.

What are the possible solutions to overcome this problem?

I am using python 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding python's GIL, I would recommend using this link: http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

From python wiki:

The GIL is controversial because it prevents multithreaded CPython programs from taking full advantage of multiprocessor systems in certain situations. Note that potentially blocking or long-running operations, such as I/O, image processing, and NumPy number crunching, happen outside the GIL. Therefore it is only in multithreaded programs that spend a lot of time inside the GIL, interpreting CPython bytecode, that the GIL becomes a bottleneck.

There are discussions on eliminating the GIL, but I guess its not achieved yet. If you really want to achieve multi-threading for your custom code, you can also switch to Java.

Do see if that helps.